# SqlAlchemy using a query with join, how to get only columns from one entity instead of both?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two models Employee and UnionEmployees.
I can join the two based on employeeid like this:

```
query = session.query(Employee,UnionEmployees)\
.filter(Employee.employeeid==UnionEmployees.employeeid)\
.filter_by(union_status='active')
```

Looking at the SQL under the hood using statement.compile

```
sql = str(query.statement.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect()))
```

I am seeing the select statement look like this:

```
select Employee.employeeid, Employee.first_name....UnionEmployee.employeeId, UnionEmployee.first_name...
...
from Employee join UnionEmployee
on Employee.employeeid = UnionEmployee.employeeid
where UnionEmployee.union_status = 'active'
```

Is there a way to alter the query so that the sql statement compiled from it only performs selects for a single entity instead of both? I would like to avoid getting redundant data if I know for sure that I only want users from one entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use explicit join:

```
query(Employee).join(UnionEmployees, Employee.employeeid == UnionEmployee.employeeid).filter(...)
```